# Why is this if statement not affected by my input?

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I want to build an algorithm who convert AM/PM to the 24hours format. It's not finished, but the code I have so far is behaving strangely.

When I give the input `"25:05:45PM"`, it should enter the first branch of the first `if` statement, but should *not* enter the second `if` statement. I've checked the condition, and it's definitely `false`. My brain is melting.

Here is the code :

```js
function conversionTime(s) {
  if (s.includes('PM')) {
    let temp = s.slice(0, 8).split(':');
    if (temp[0] >= 01 && temp[0] <= 12); {
      temp[0] = Number(temp[0]) + 12;
      return temp.join(':')
    }
  } else if (s.includes('AM')) {
    let temp2 = s.slice(0, 8).split(':');
    return temp2
  }
}
console.log(conversionTime("25:05:45PM"))
```

Comment: An `if (s.includes('AM'))` _inside_ of an `if (s.includes('PM'))` doesn't sound that useful to me, unless your string contains _both_ `AM` and `PM`. That's probably your issue.

Comment: Hi @wizzwizz4, i just edited my function, thanks for noticing, i messed up with the ```.

Comment: @CherryDT No, that's not it; there's a `}` hidden after `return temp.join(':')`.

Comment: Oh... Okay, so the moral of the story is: **Indent and format your code properly, folks!** For the sake of your own sanity and everyone's who is trying to help you.

Comment: Yes, sorry for that, i have messed up it, i'm trying to learn to have the cleanest code, i promise my next questions will be perfect @CherryDT

Comment: how can you have an hour value `> 12` in an `AM/PM` time presentation system?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Gotcha.

```
if (temp[0] >= 01 && temp[0] <= 12);
```

This semicolon is the culprit! It's saying "the `if` statement is over, no need to do anything", so your code is being interpreted like:

```
if (temp[0] >= 01 && temp[0] <= 12);

{
  temp[0] = Number(temp[0]) + 12;
  return temp.join(':');
}
```

The code in the block will always run. This feature exists so you can make full use of `let`'s scoping:

```js
let x = "outside";
console.log(x);
{
  let x = "inside";
  console.log(x);
}
console.log(x);
```

Well, *really* it exists because that's how C works – it predates the `let` statement – but that's what it's useful for these days.

Comment: ... I love you more than you can ever imagine, you opened my mind.
If i could thumbs up your response i would.
Thank you so much !

Comment: @StefancicSamuel You could accept it (the tick mark below the voting arrows) if it solved your problem. Though your algorithm does have some other issues you'll probably have noticed.

Comment: If you don't manage to fix those on your own (and I'm sure you'll be able to get at least some of them!), please ask a separate question. Feel free to post a link to it here.

Comment: Oh yes ! I forgot about that.
Yeah, i have some more statements to make, and i will gladly fail while doing them, but i will learn so much from it so i do not want to know them yet :)

Comment: Alright ! I will definitively create new posts if i encounter some problems and add the link to know the path we already made :)

Comment: what is the value `25`? a day ? it can't be a hour value !  so please explain me !

Comment: @MisterJojo You mean _your_ days don't have 26 hours in them? :-P I imagine this test-case is meant to end up as `01:05:45`, but the code to do that hasn't been written yet. (And OP is learning, so no spoilers!)

Comment: @MisterJojo Yes. That is, indeed, the point of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I Will do that this way..

```js
function conversionTime(timeAPM)
  {
  let [h,m,s,apm] = timeAPM.match(/(\d+)|(\w+)/g);  

  if (timeAPM !== `${h}:${m}:${s}${apm}`
   || isNaN(h) || isNaN(m) || isNaN(s) 
   || (apm !== 'AM' && apm !== 'PM')    
   ) return undefined;

  if (apm === 'PM' && h <= 12 ) h = +h +12;
  return `${h}:${m}:${s}`;
  }

console.log(conversionTime("25:05:45PM"))
```

I don't know if it's intentional or not on his part, but the PO's code also returns `undefined`. Apart from his attachment to the `AM`/`PM` labels, the OP gives no explanation on the validity of the entry.

So this second version is content to check that there are indeed `3`  numerical values, separate by `:`, and directly followed by  `AM` or `PM`.

the number of digits of these numbers is unknown : His test uses an hour = `25` while it is an `AM/PM` presentation. So why not seconds or minutes expressed with `40` digits...

I'm not claiming my regex is the best in the universe.

I could also have added in my code:

```
console.log(conversionTime("10:31:25BAM")) // -> undefined
console.log(conversionTime("1:3:5abc"))    // -> undefined
console.log(conversionTime("1:3zzzz"))     // -> undefined
console.log(conversionTime("a:10:15PM"))   // -> undefined
console.log(conversionTime("285::4875PM")) // -> undefined
// or more absurd:
console.log(conversionTime("285:1505:4875PM")) // -> 285:1505:4875
```

Comment: Thanks ! I was wondering on the regex utilisation, but i still have some work to do to completely comprehend your code :)

Comment: @StefancicSamuel This code is just a complicated version of what you've got now – except that it returns a string in both cases (AM and PM); a simple fix in your version, except that that's the _wrong behaviour anyway_. It contains all the other bugs yours has, and (imo) is less clear than what you've got already; that `Object.assign` bit is positively _arcane_, and the `isNan` checks would be completely unnecessary if the regular expression were more sensible.

Comment: I'd suggest `/(\d\d):(\d\d):(\d\d)(AM|PM)/.exec(timeAPM)` (untested) as the regular expression; that, with a null check, would be shorter, simpler and clearer. If you want to accept things like `262:1:25PM`, make it `\d+` or `\d*` as appropriate.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 I added some explanations for you,